# C# Outlook Add-On: Check Calendars Availability

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am working on an add-in for Outlook using C# and I want to be able to check the availability of calendars (mine and others'). I tried using GetSharedDefaultFolder() but it only worked with those who specifically gave me permission, even though all calendars in my company can be viewed by others (we can see the subject and times of appointments). Is there anyway I can get these information? Thanks.

**EDIT**: I want to emphasize that my problem is with GetSharedDefaultFolder() rather than GetDefaultFolder() (i.e. viewing others' calendars.) Also, I only need to be able to check others' calendars availability, as opposed to having full access to the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not access the folder directly - use Recipient.FreeBusy or AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy

Answer (score 1):

Try This>>

```
 public void GetAllCalendarItems()
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

            oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
            CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);            outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
            outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
            {
                if (item.IsRecurring)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp = item.GetRecurrencePattern();
                    DateTime first = new DateTime(2008, 8, 31, item.Start.Hour, item.Start.Minute, 0);
                    DateTime last = new DateTime(2008, 10, 1);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem recur = null;



                    for (DateTime cur = first; cur <= last; cur = cur.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur);
                            MessageBox.Show(recur.Subject + " -> " + cur.ToLongDateString());
                        }
                        catch
                        { }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.Subject + " -> " + item.Start.ToLongDateString());
                }
            }

        }
```

Seems problem similar to this>

http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=8953

So follow discussion on this link. It might helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. This can be used to view my calendar, but how about others?! As I mentioned above, the problem happens with GetSharedDefaultFolder() rather than GetDefaultFolder().

Comment: go through link in my answer