# Outlook VSTO Addin COMException Cannot load free/busy information

Tags: c#, com, outlook, vsto

In my Outlook VSTO Region I am adding attendees from all address books and looking for their free/busy status, but I always get this error

`

```
Outlook.NameSpace mapi = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var reci = mapi.CreateRecipient("abc@mydomain.com");
string st = reci.FreeBusy(new DateTime(2016, 3, 10), 60, true);

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147352567
  Message=Cannot load free/busy information.
  Source=Microsoft Outlook
  ErrorCode=-2147352567
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient.FreeBusy(DateTime Start, Int32 MinPerChar, Object CompleteFormat)
```

`

I have also tried doing it from the `AddressEntry` object, still the same error. Any help/ suggestions will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I am already using the `Recipient. FreeBusy` method as suggested in similar post but I still get the error to which I couldn't find any useful info.

EDIT#2:
Strangely it works on second attempt, yes in try/catch it is working on 2nd attempt, any ideas why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Outlook Add-On: Check Calendars Availability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545818/c-sharp-outlook-add-on-check-calendars-availability)